# Dynamic URL based on user_metadata

Tags: urls, user-meta

I want to know how can I dynamically change the page a user is taken to when they select a URL....using wordpress user metadata fields?

My users have either selected "male" or "female" as their gender in their profile and the value is stored in a mysql database in the "usermeta" table.

And I have created 2 pages:

www.example.com/male

www.example.com/female

Is there a way to use a current logged in user's metadata field value in a URL to send them to the correct page?

meta_key = "user_gender"

www.example.com/"user_gender"

Is this possible in wordpress?

Please help!

Comment: You can use `get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_gender' )` to retrieve the user meta value. You can build your redirect with `wp_redirect()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris! Would you be able to give an example of the code I would need to write to include in wordpress for 1) getting the 'user_gender' variable and 2) to append the variable to the URL. I am using a Snippet plugin. Sorry, I am a new to custom PHP/javascript coding.

Comment: You can store it into a variable like this `$user_gender = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_gender' );` and then redirect with `wp_redirect('/'.$user_gender); exit;`. This code will need to run before any content is output (basically before your `<!doctype>`) or the redirect won't work (if I remember right).